# extend multiple core controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have `MY_Controller` in core that extends CI_Controller. That works fine. But, I want to create another core controller named `MY_Controller_2` for some reasons. Can I do this in codeigniter? If yes then what will be the changes in `config` file?

**config.php**

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

**Directory Structure**

```
core/MY_Controller
core/MY_Controller_2    <-------- I want another controller too.
```

**MY_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

.....
```

so, basically, some of the controller files, I want to extend  from `MY_Controller` and some from `MY_Controller_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing this at the bottom of your config.php

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

This will load all core controllers.

Comment: `Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IFH_Website/application/config/config.php on line 531` getting this after adding above code